# Fail to inport malloc memory as VkDeviceMemory

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I'm trying to import a host memory as a staging buffer in Vulkan.

In the future, the plan is to use a shared memory as staging vertex buffer (in the host). But I can't manage to successfully import a previously allocated memory into vulkan.

The return of `vkAllocateMemory` is `VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY`.

Here is my code:

```cpp
void createMallocedBuffer(VkPhysicalDevice const& physicalDevice, 
                           VkDevice const& device,
                           void * data,
                           VkBuffer & buffer,
                           VkDeviceMemory& bufferMemory )
{
    VkPhysicalDeviceExternalMemoryHostPropertiesEXT externalMemHostProp;
    externalMemHostProp.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HOST_PROPERTIES_EXT;
    externalMemHostProp.pNext = nullptr;

    VkPhysicalDeviceProperties physicalDeviceProps;

    VkPhysicalDeviceProperties2 physicalDeviceProps2;
    physicalDeviceProps2.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2;
    physicalDeviceProps2.pNext = &externalMemHostProp;
    physicalDeviceProps2.properties = physicalDeviceProps;

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2(physicalDevice, &physicalDeviceProps2);

    data = malloc(externalMemHostProp.minImportedHostPointerAlignment);

    VkExternalMemoryHandleTypeFlagBits externalMemoryFlagBits {
        VK_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_HOST_ALLOCATION_BIT_EXT
    };

    VkMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT pointersProps {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_HOST_POINTER_PROPERTIES_EXT,
        .pNext = nullptr,
    };

    vkGetMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT(device, 
                                        externalMemoryFlagBits,
                                        data,
                                        &pointersProps);

    VkExternalMemoryBufferCreateInfo externalMemCreateInfo {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext = nullptr,
        .handleTypes = externalMemoryFlagBits,
    };

    VkBufferUsageFlags bufferUsage {
        VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT
    };

    VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &externalMemCreateInfo,
        .flags = 0,
        .size = externalMemHostProp.minImportedHostPointerAlignment,
        .usage = bufferUsage,
        .sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE,
    };

    if (vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferInfo, nullptr, &buffer) != VK_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create buffer!");
    }

    VkMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT memoryHostPointerProperties {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_HOST_POINTER_PROPERTIES_EXT,
    };

    if (auto result = vkGetMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT(device, externalMemoryFlagBits, data, &memoryHostPointerProperties); 
        result != VK_SUCCESS) 
    {
        // printError(result);
    }

    VkMemoryPropertyFlags memProperties {
        VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT
    };

    VkImportMemoryHostPointerInfoEXT importHostPointerInfo {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMPORT_MEMORY_HOST_POINTER_INFO_EXT,
        .pNext = nullptr,
        .handleType = externalMemoryFlagBits,
        .pHostPointer = data,
    };

    VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
    vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, buffer, &memRequirements);
    auto memTypeIndex = findMemoryType(physicalDevice, memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, memProperties);
    
    VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo {
        .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO,
        .pNext = &importHostPointerInfo,
        .allocationSize = externalMemHostProp.minImportedHostPointerAlignment,
        .memoryTypeIndex = memTypeIndex,
    };

    if (auto result = vkAllocateMemory(device, &allocInfo, nullptr, &bufferMemory); 
        result != VK_SUCCESS) 
    {
        // printError(result);
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate buffer memory!");
    }

    vkBindBufferMemory(device, buffer, bufferMemory, 0);
}
```

```cpp
uint32_t findMemoryType(VkPhysicalDevice const& physicalDevice, 
                        uint32_t const typeFilter, 
                        VkMemoryPropertyFlags const& properties )
{
    VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties memProperties;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(physicalDevice, &memProperties);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < memProperties.memoryTypeCount; ++i)
    {
        auto const typeSelect = (typeFilter & (1 << i));
        auto const flagSelect = (memProperties.memoryTypes[i].propertyFlags & properties);

        if (typeSelect && (flagSelect == properties))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    throw std::runtime_error("failed to find suitable memory type!");
}
```

Comment: elaborate what error

Comment: "*`data = malloc(externalMemHostProp.minImportedHostPointerAlignment);`*" I see nothing in this statement that causes the allocated memory to have the required alignment.

Comment: 1. What is the actual error? You trap the exception from the allocation method but don't pass it up. 2. What is the `memTypeIndex`  returned from (presumably) a helper method?  Is it a valid memory type?

Comment: @krOoze the error code is  VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DEVICE_MEMORY. Is strange because the host is not out of memory.

Comment: @stridecolossus I updated the question to include the helper function. I'm just getting the index to the memory type that matches what I need. Should be valid. But I'm new to vulkan, so not sure.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm getting the device minimum size and passing it no malloc, shouldn't it return an alligned memory. If I'm mistaken please correct me.

Comment: You fail to check `data` against `nullptr`. You call `vkGetMemoryHostPointerPropertiesEXT()` twice, but in either case you do not use the output.

Comment: Suggest also trying without the alignment extension to see whether basic memory allocation works first, i.e. populate the allocationSize in `VkMemoryAllocateInfo` to the size returned in the memory requirements.